# Does Wikileaks have direct ties with US governmental organizations?

Tags: politics, government, wikileaks

According to [this blog post](http://tbrnews.org/wordpress/?p=381) post (I agree, this is not a very valid source of information), Julian Assange had ties with US government workers, especially in the CIA:

> The sender is talking about John Young who runs Cryptome, an alleged “leak” site. The IPTO mentioned in the text is The Information Processing Techniques Office (IPTO) of DARPA, an adjunct of the Army! There are more references to Assange’s DoD employment that are explosive in that they clearly reveal a major, clandestine, war going on between the U.S. Army, its intelligence sources and the CIA. The Army saw, and sees, the CIA (aka ‘the Company’) as destabilizing foreign areas that eventually lead to situations that the Army has to become involved in i.e. Afghanistan, Iraq, etc so their program has been, and is, to offset the CIA’s disruptive campaigns (like the so-called ‘Orange Revolution’ in the Ukraine) by disrupting their plans.

In addition, after the first US diplomatic cables leaks back in November 2010, several individuals pointed out that the leaked information were of no great importance, and did not disclose any sensitive information. In fact, according to [several](http://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2010/12/03/wikileaks-le-mythe-de-la-transparence_1448207_3232.html) [french journalists](http://www.lcp.fr/emissions/docs-ad-hoc/vod/11088-wikileaks-enquete-sur-un-contre-pouvoir) working at Le Monde, the information disclosed by the Cable gates is mostly information which was already known by journalists or highly probable.

Hence, any conspiracy theorist could suppose that Wikileaks is operated under the hood by US governmental organizations, maybe in hopes of limiting whistle blowing information providers.

Is there any additional information which could link Wikileaks to US government agencies?

Comment: I recall the former Wikileaks members who broke off and started Openleaks accused Wikileaks of essentially being a branch of the US government. Members of Wikileaks reciprocated, accusing Openleaks of being a CIA front. I expect a great deal of plausible deniability, short of a confession by the CIA.

Comment: just having people in government agencies handing you information doesn't mean you have "direct ties" with them. It most likely means there are people in those agencies who're acting against policy, iow traitors.

Comment: Jwenting, you are right. That is why I am skeptic about Wikileaks having _direct ties_ instead of just informers who go against policy.

Comment: @ChrisR - If wikileaks has informers at the CIA then it would have **Direct** Ties.  If it knew someone who had a source at the CIA then it would have **Indirect** Ties.  If they knew a guy who knew a guy who's sister dated a guy who... well then it would just be a made up story about a guy :)

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt : The Openleaks guys never claimed that Wikileaks is a branch of the US government. There might be people who profit from making people think that'S the case but the Openleaks guys didn't make such statements.